# cannot play iPad <audio> over https

Tags: ios, ipad, html, safari, mobile-safari

I am trying to play HTML5  on iPad Safari . 
Below is my code;

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.type = "audio/mpeg";
    audio.src = audioUrl;         
    x.appendChild(audio);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
```

Now my audio files are called over https and for some reasons, it cannot play audio over https...I mean if I try manually playing mp3 files on http, it plays them fine..

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: *manually*? Are you sure the problem is the HTTPS and not the way you are building it in JS?

Comment: Yes, i am 100% sure on that...coz if I manually i.e. hardcode http path, it plays the mp3 on iPad..But by default it gets https path in audioUrl

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.type = "audio/mp3";
audio.src = audioUrl;         
x.appendChild(audio);
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

audio/mpeg may be the issue. Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports uncompressed WAV and AIF audio, MP3 audio, and AAC-LC or HE-AAC audio. HE-AAC is the preferred format.