# HTML5 audio over HTTPS won't work on smartphones?

Tags: iphone, android, html, audio, https

I have tested some droids and iphones and have not found a phone that works. Basically if I use `<audio src="http://....`  everything works. When I change it to `<audio src="https://.....` the file plays fine on computers but not on smart phones. Any ideas why?

See similar posts:

[cannot play iPad <audio> over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306508/cannot-play-ipad-audio-over-https)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19958)

Comment: you seem to be missing part of your question, please edit.

Comment: I think for audio video streaming on android https protocol doesnt support. Look at here [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think for audio video streaming on android https protocol doesnt support. Look at here [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).